# Tailwind's default colors are not working, only white and custom colors

Tags: django, tailwind-css

I am building a web application using the Django framework and installed Tailwind CSS using this tutorial: https://django-tailwind.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html. It worked fine initially, but now when I reload my project after closing VScode, my colors stop working.

For an example,
I'll be creating a new line of HTML and use:

```html
<body>
    <div class="bg-blue-400 font-bold p-4 text-4xl">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the background just goes immediately to white. I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling and checking my directories and still have no solution.

I have also found that only my custom colors work when I reload my project.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
       
        '../templates/**/*.html',

        '../../templates/**/*.html',

        '../../**/templates/**/*.html',

    ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'jcblue1': '#5CB5FD',
        'spook': '#3C4856',
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

^this is my tailwind.config file.

Comment: Did tailwind build them in the output CSS file?

Comment: Please add the `tailwind.config.js` to your question.

Comment: /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
       
        '../templates/**/*.html',

        '../../templates/**/*.html',

        '../../**/templates/**/*.html',

    ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'jcblue1': '#5CB5FD',
        'spook': '#3C4856',
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}